# Possible to create a global scope closure in javascript?

Tags: javascript, scope, global-variables

Goal is to be able to allow a global variable (such as `currentAccount`) to refer to multiple values at the same time based on the execution context.

```
var context = new Context();
context.currentAccount = "mine";
context.execute(function() {
   // any code in or called by this function 
   // needs access to the `currentAccount` variable

   // for example
   var model = new Model();
   model.doSomething(); // model needs to be able to refer to `currentAccount`
});

context = new Context();
context.currentAccount = "yours";
context.execute(function() {
   ...
   model.doSomething(); // `currentAccount` => "yours"
});
```

Comment: As to why, the app I'm working with was never intended to allow a user to work on multiple accounts at the same time. Now it's looking like there may be a valid case for doing so.  There are three or four of these global session variables used pervasively across the codebase.

Comment: Would it be easiest to just execute each "context" in its own iframe?

Comment: I would recommend rewriting your code to pass the `currentAccount` reference around as needed (either pass it to the `Model` constructor or to the `model.doSomething()` calls, whichever fits your model), instead of trying to work it around like you're trying.

Comment: It feels like that approach would be too invasive.  Just about every single class in the codebase references these global session variables (similar to the `current_user` approach in rails -- imagine having to pass the user as a parameter to every method call).

Comment: That's why you might add it as a parameter to your constructors or as a property on your instances, and change the references to your global variables into references to instance properties. This is precisely the reason why it is _extremely_ advisable to avoid using global variables in the first place.